# Slow down location.reload() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, show-hide, jquery

Is there a way to slow down `location.reload()`?

Currently I'm using `.toggle("slow")` in in some and `.hide("slow")` in others to show modal animations. One of the functions calls a refresh but the animation doesn't complete prior to the reload. It starts and gets halfway finished and then just gets cut off. I like to have it wait until the animation finishes and then reload.

```
$(".modal-box button").click(function(){
    $(".modal-box").hide("slow");
    if ($(this).is("#reset")){
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do instead is define a callback function for the animation that will run whenever the animation actually finishes.

```
$(".modal-box button").click(function(){
    var self = this; //keep the correct scope
    $(".modal-box").hide("slow", function() {
        if ($(self).is("#reset")){
            location.reload();
        }
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".modal-box button").click(function(){
    var self = this;
    $(".modal-box").hide("slow", function(){
        if ($(self).is("#reset")){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it the callback of the animation:

```
$(".modal-box").hide('slow', location.reload);
```